# When is area of regular $n$-gon expressible by radicals?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, radicals, polygons

I had a look at the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area). As there are only $20$ values published I noted that the area values given as radicals ( of square roots ) correspond to values of $n$ for which the $n$-gon is constructible. But I am now surprised that for the values $n=15$ and $n=17$ whose $n$-gons are constructible there is no expression with radicals given.

Why is that the case ? Is a general theorem known about the phenomenon ? What are the values of $n$ for which the area of regular $n$-gon is expressible by radicals ?

Comment: If by radicals you mean $k$-th roots, general $k$, which is the standard meaning, then all. If you restrict to square roots, which you seem to be doing, then iff $n\ge 3$ is a product of distinct Fermat primes times a power of $2$, possibly $1$.  Doing your example of $15$ is easy. There are explicit constructions for $17$. The first one was given by Gauss when he was quite young.

Comment: Oh - it seems the Wikipedia table contains now the value of $n=15$. When I understand correctly the value of $n=17$ is simply missing because the expression is far too long and complicated... ;)

Comment: It is indeed messy, though it comes in principle fairly easily from theory. The other known Fermat primes  $\gt 17$, namely $257$ and $65537$ are very messy.

Answer (score 1):

> *But I am now surprised that for the values $n=15$ and $n=17$ whose $n$-gons are constructible there is no expression with radicals given. Why is that the case ?*

Probably because of the fact that they would look something like this:

[image]

---

> *When I understand correctly, the value of $n=17$ is simply missing because the expression is far too long and complicated...* ;-$)$

Yeah, one might be slightly tempted to say that...

Comment: These can be computed by hand —although the expressions one gets are slightly different than those, if one is smart when doing it; Gauss essentially does this in his Disq. Arith.

Comment: (The next two Fermat primes were in fact done *explicitly*; the largest one is done [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/resolveppn/GDZPPN002496585))

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I believe that your last comment is misplaced. :-$)$